# Renaming the multiple sheets with the month extracted from respective columns

Tags: vba, excel, date, rename

I have 10 sheets in the same workbook. Each sheet contains data for only specific month (10 different months). If I have time format as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` in column D and I have a dynamic number of rows. I want the code to read the month number from column D and rename the sheet with the month name respectively.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what is your problem? is it the extraction of the month from the data in the column? or is it the renaming of the worksheet? show us your code and tell us your problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far and it would be good to have some example inputs and outputs maybe some pics or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over the worksheets use a simple `for` loop

```
 For Each ws In Worksheets
```

Inside the loop, select the sheet

```
      Sheets(ws.Name).Select
```

And extract the month

```
      sheetdate = Range("D1").Value
      mn = MonthName(Month(sheetdate))
```

Finally, rename the worksheet

```
      ActiveSheet.Name = mn
```

And close the loop

```
  Next ws
```

So, putting all pieces together and simplifying the code, just try this

```
  For Each ws In Worksheets
      ws.Name =MonthName(Month(ws.Range("D1").Value))
  Next ws
```

Comment: I was just able to extract the month number and print it in some column. I will explain the details and post image links whenever required from next time onwards. Both the above codes worked. Thanks.

Comment: If I want to rename it with Month name  and year for ex. May 2015,       Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Name = MonthName(Month(sheetobject.Range("D2"))) & Format(Year(sheetobject.Range("D2")), "yyyy")   I tried this. But its not working. What is the mistake in the code after &?

Comment: divide and conquer.  First, take the date `dt = ws.range("D1")` then extract month  `mn = MonthName(Month(dt))` and year `yn = Year(dt)`  then build together in the result  `ws.name = mn & " " & yn`

Comment: the problem was you were trying to  `format(year(date)` instead of the correct `format(date)` or simply taking `year(date)`

Answer (score 0):

Here my approach,

```
Public Sub changeSheetName()

    'Loop all sheet from workbook
    For Each aSheet In Worksheets

        'Get date from "D2" cell and change to month name
        'And set it to sheet name
        aSheet.Name = MonthName(Month(aSheet.Range("D2"))) & " " & Year(aSheet.Range("D2"))

    Next aSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to rename it with Month name and year for ex. May 2015, Sheets(sheetobject.Index + 1).Name = MonthName(Month(sheetobject.Range("D2"))) & Format(Year(sheetobject.Range("D2")), "yyyy") I tried this. But its not working. What is the mistake in the code after &?